# How can I use Gmail API filters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I have got all the Gmail messages in my DOM. And then apply simple filter(List filter in JS) to filter from those emails. But my requirement is to just fetch those emails that match my input in search box. In short, I don't wanna get all the emails first, I just wanna enter the specific email and it gives me matching results.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions. Also, you have not accepted answers to any of your previous questions. If your previous questions have been answered, click the empty check mark next to the answer, to help others find it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the Gmail API filters using JavaScript, you will need to do the following:

Set up a project on the Google Cloud Console and enable the Gmail API.

Create credentials (such as an API key or OAuth client ID) to authenticate your JavaScript app with the Gmail API.

Use a JavaScript library such as the Google API client library for JavaScript to make requests to the Gmail API.

Once you have authenticated your app, you can use the gmail.users.messages.list method to retrieve messages that match your search criteria. The method takes an options object that allows you to specify the q parameter, which is a query string that filters the messages based on various criteria. For example, to search for messages from a specific sender you can use the query string from:sender@example.com

Then you can use JavaScript array filter method to filter the response messages based on your requirements.

Here is an example of how you can use the gmail.users.messages.list method with the q parameter to retrieve messages that match a specific search criteria:

You can also use the gmail.users.messages.get method to retrieve a specific message by its ID.
You will have to take care of the authentication and authorization part using the credentials you have created.